# Python - Recursively find parent tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I have a a binary tree, with only self._root and self._nodes. Is there anyway I could figure out how to find a parent tree of the current tree through the constructor?

```
class BinaryTree:
    """
    - If _root is None, then _nodes is empty and _parent_tree is None
    - nodes is allowed to contain empty nodes
    - if _parent_tree is not empty, then self is in _parent_tree._nodes
    """
    def __init__(self, root, nodes):
        """Initialize a new BinaryTree.
        @type self: BinaryTree
        @type root: object
        @type nodes: list[BinaryTree]
        @rtype: None
        """
        self._root = root
        self._nodes = nodes
        self._parent_tree = None


        """Implement _parent_tree"""

        if self._root is not None:
            """implement"""
        else:
            pass
```

To be honest, I have no idea of how to even start this. How would I know any other BinaryTree objects without constructing this one first. What would I be recursively looking through? I can't possibly look through this BinaryTree

Comment: Is there another object? Perhaps a Node?

Comment: From what you have here it seems that the only way you can set a `_parent_tree` is when you set a particular tree's subtree. Without already having a `parent_tree` there's nothing else linking them

Comment: does your self._subtrees has reference to left child and right child i.e. a list [left,right]? Also what do you mean by parent tree, the parent node ?

Comment: @JeffMandell no other object, which is why I'm so confused as how to solve this

Comment: @Shasha99 no, subtrees is just a list of other Binarytrees, so a tree could have 3 subtrees. Also a parent tree means that it is a tree of the current tree that is being initialized. So this self would be the subtree of the parent tree

Comment: I am not able to understand why are you calling it a binary tree then ? And please add some image how you tree will look like.

Comment: @Shasha99 From my understanding, this is actually a type of binary tree, its very basic. you can see images of trees with more than two subtrees here http://i.stack.imgur.com/j7A1f.jpg or here http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-UA.0102-001/TwoThreeTree1.gif

Comment: As per my understanding, first one is called n-ary tree and second one will be called ternary tree. Also for n-ary tree you need a list of n child references for each node.  So you should not use the term subtrees, better to use child nodes.

Comment: @Shasha99 Thank you, I've changed it to nodes, but I still need a way to find the parent tree

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127923/discussion-between-shasha99-and-theo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do good for you :

```
class BinaryTree:
  def __init__(self, root, nodes):
    self._root = root
    self._nodes = nodes
    self._parent_tree = None

    if self._root is not None:
        for node in self._nodes:
            if node is not None:
                node._parent_tree = self
    else:
        pass
```